# nslookup times out when result is 127.0.0.1

Tags: windows, dns, nslookup

I have set up a subdomain with an A record of 127.0.0.1 (set up more than 24 hours ago at the authoritative server, just like how I would set up a normal subdomain)  for the sake of development. Let's say it's localhost.example.com. I can use nslookup to find this from work without any problems:

```
$ nslookup localhost.jasperhorn.nl
Server:  dc01.[...]
Address:  10.1.1.50

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    localhost.jasperhorn.nl
Address:  127.0.0.1
```

However, from home I'm not getting any response:

```
$ nslookup localhost.jasperhorn.nl
Server:  dsldevice.lan
Address:  192.168.1.1

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to dsldevice.lan timed-out
```

When I add the nameserver explicitly while running nslookup at home, it works without any problems:

```
$ nslookup localhost.jasperhorn.nl ns1.flexwebhosting.nl
Server:  ns1.flexwebhosting.nl
Address:  82.192.67.204

Name:    localhost.jasperhorn.nl
Address:  127.0.0.1
```

(At work, adding the nameserver causes problems, but I assume that is because of a firewall and unrelated to the issues at home.)

When trying the same call from two of my servers (both running linux) I get the correct answer (127.0.0.1) both when specifying and when not specifying the nameserver.

Does this point to a buggy router or could there be something else that is going on?

Comment: You "other location" is using a different DNS server than the first, and based on the information you've provided I'm not sure why you think this would work.  Did you also put an A record into that DNS server?  Does the 192.x.x.x DNS forward to the 10.x.x.x DNS server?

Comment: The lack of information and use of generic domain names is what threw me.  No mention originally that the DNS was a public DNS. Anyhow... If you explicitly specify (to NSLookup) the DNS server that the A record exists on, does it resolve at the second location?  Are both locations set to use the same public DNS server? How much time elapse between the time you added the DNS record and when you tested it from the 2nd location (perhaps it just hadn't propagated yet)?

Comment: No answer, but yeah, that bit about the work DNS timing out when specifying the NS (opposite of home) seems pretty weird. :/

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I guess I figured that bit out: it must be the firewall at my workplace using a whitelist approach for dns servers. That means the answer to your question becomes a full "yes, it works when I specify the server'

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I removed the comments are adding the information to the question. Now, I can post again without the site complaining about extended discussion :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I sadly distrust some of the results you provided.  (I'm not saying that you are inaccurately reporting the results.  I'm saying I distrust the results.)

First, just to get this out of the way, your current question shows:

`nslookup localhost.jasperhorn.nl ns1.flexwebhosting.nl`

I get the same results as you.  However, in this case, you are not asking them about localhost.example.com, but you are asking them about localhost.jasperhorn.nl.  This is different than asking them about localhost.example.com.  When I do that:

`nslookup localhost.example.com ns1.flexwebhosting.nl
Server:  ns1.flexwebhosting.nl
Address:  82.192.67.204`

*** ns1.flexwebhosting.nl can't find localhost.example.com: Query refused

They provided you with results.  For me, who is in WA State of USA, halfway around the world from this DNS server's location that is presumably in the Netherlands, I find that they did set up a DNS server that receives my traffic, and they validated whether I was authorized to use them, and they figured out that I wasn't, and they bothered to send a reply (using the DNS protocol) which let me know that they refused my query.  Or maybe they just quickly closed/declined the UDP port 53 connection.  Either way, they somehow quickly let me know that I shouldn't bother trying to get DNS results from them.  If you use the same DNS server, it seems they are spending time validating your permission to use the server.  (Note that you might not be using the same computer as a DNS server, even if you specify the same IPv4 address, as they may route internal IPv4 traffic different than external IPv4 traffic).

So, next I looked up a list of DNS root servers, and tried this:

`nslookup localhost.example.com 198.41.0.4`

Partial Results:

`Server:  UnKnown
Address:  198.41.0.4`

Name:    localhost.example.com
Served by:
- m.gtld-servers.net
          192.55.83.30
          com

Okay, so it doesn't want to tell me.  It says to check 192.55.83.30 for an answer of things related to "com".  (That makes sense since "localhost.example.com." is within "com.", I'm showing the often-implied final period.)

okay, now let's look at what the right answer is:

`nslookup localhost.example.com m.gtld-servers.net`

Key part of results:

`Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.55.83.30`

Name:    localhost.example.com
Served by:
- a.iana-servers.net
          199.43.132.53
          2001:500:8c::53
          example.com
- b.iana-servers.net
          199.43.133.53
          2001:500:8d::53
          example.com

Oh, they don't want to tell me either.  They do tell me that a.iana-servers.net is a better place to ask about `localhost.example.com.`  Fine, I'll do that.

`nslookup localhost.example.com a.iana-servers.net
Server:  a.iana-servers.net
Address:  199.43.132.53`

*** `a.iana-servers.net can't find localhost.example.com: Non-existent domain`

Okay.  There you go.  That is the official correct answer.  All other DNS servers should provide the same answer.  Let's check that out a bit:

`nslookup localhost.example.com google-public-dns-a.google.com
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8`

*** google-public-dns-a.google.com can't find localhost.example.com: Non-existent domain

Here's another nameserver:

`nslookup localhost.example.com resolver1.opendns.com
Server:  resolver1.opendns.com
Address:  208.67.222.222`

*** `resolver1.opendns.com can't find localhost.example.com: Non-existent domain`

Okay, so those reputable sources are agreeing with the officially correct source.  So, for the first results you show, where 10.1.1.50 (which is a private IPv4 address, which points to different equipment based on what network you are on), the device that responded provided a non-authoritative answer that does not match the actually correct answer.  Instead of saying the domain was non-existent, it said: `Address:  127.0.0.1`

Shame on that device.  I would call that a misconfiguration.  Perhaps a rather sensible one: "example.com" is often treated in special ways, so the fact that "example.com" might provide interesting results doesn't necessarily mean that the DNS server would do a bad job at the standard task of looking up non-special domains.  Still, it would be my preference to see that the device gives correct information.

Now, finally, let's discuss the router.  The router is not responding.  This leaves me to wonder what happens if you give the router another non-existent domain.

Now, I already said why I wouldn't worry too much about results from the "example.com" domain (because some people might treat it special; treating that wrong doesn't necessarily indicate that other domains would also be treated wrong).  So let me stop focusing on the "example.com" name, and just generalize the situation a bit (pretending like this might also happen with other names).  What happens when the nameserver provides incorrect results?  I'm going to just ignore which domain name you specified, and discuss how to handle a device that doesn't respond correctly.

That would suggest a buggy nameserver.  From your example output, the buggy nameserver is at 192.168.1.1 which is called "dsldevice.lan". If that is your router (which does seem likely, based on the name), then that is the source of the problem.  That device seems to be trying to outsmart you, by operating in special ways with certain results, and is doing so in violation of how DNS ought to work.  If I noticed this, I would do one of:

- see if the router can be fixed, by adjusting some setting(s).  (Specifically, the settings to adjust are likely related to DNS, nameserving, etc.)
- see if the router can be fixed, by changing the firmware (to an official upgrade, or an unofficial distribution like DD-WRT).  That is how I would handle a router.  If we weren't talking about a router, I could generalize this approach by saying: "replace the DNS server (with different software)".
- simply ignore the issue, and have the router stop being the DNS server.  (The slickest way to use another DNS server may be to adjust the settings of the DHCP server that specifies which DNS server to use.  In many cases, the DHCP server may be the router.  In that case, I would adjust the DHCP settings in the router, telling the router to point devices to a different DNS server that provides results that I do trust)

Comment: I used *example.com* only as an example. I never did an actual lookup for localhost.example.com, I just replaced the real domain with example.com on this site because I didn't feel like putting the real domain on display here. And then I forgot to do the same for an edit. I'm sorry if that wasn't clear. I've edited the question to include the real domain in each sample now.

Comment: The issue here isn't any wrong answer, though. The answer you are talking about was actually the correct answer (just for a different domain). The unexpected result is the other router, which does does not respond for this domain at all. Replacing it will prove difficult (it was provided by my ISP and is the modem as well as the router), but I'd at least like to pin it down to being the router's fault.

Comment: Using a different DNS name may make many of the specific details of the shared "NSLookup" results be less helpful.  Still, recommendations (by the bullet points) at the end can still likely apply. If you also follow details of my answer, it shows me following a process which may still provide you with specific details that help when getting different results from different DNS servers.  Maybe you should mask DNS names for this question, but just know that as long as those names remain masked, that may limit/hinder possibilities of results that are more direct/specific (in my answer, or others)

Comment: Most routers don't interfere with DNS traffic that isn't directed to the routers (or, at very least, they should be able to disable any such "optimization").  If you cannot easily replace the router, and if you cannot easily adjust the router's configuration, you can probably just adjust your computer to not rely on DHCP to determine which DNS server you wish to use.  That is commonly an easy setting to adjust (unless the computer is not under your control, such as if the computer belongs to a business that applies security that prevents easy tampering with such settings).